# SQL Server 2008: ODBC connection problems

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I am able to successfully connect from access 2007 into SQL Server 2008 using ODBC; however it prompts me with the password each time.

When I try to open the linked table from access it says connection filed: `SQLSTATE '28000' SQL SERVER ERROR 18452 [microsoft][odbc.........[][]] login failed. the loin is frmo an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication.`

However I am NOT using win authentication, I'm using SQL Server authentication

After this error, I get a prompt for SQL Server login where I enter credentials and then it works fine

here's my connection string:

```
[ODBC]
Driver=SQL Server
Uid=myuser
Pwd=mypass
App=2007 microsoft office system
server=servername
```

Is there something I can adjust with my connection string to force it to connect with SQL Server authentication instead of windows auth?

Comment: @marc_s: any ideas? funny thing is that it happens every time i open access; however after i enter the password, it is fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you link tables, there is a option to check that says to remember your password.

So, during the table link process there is a box you need to check to remember your password. You will find that box here:

[image]

So, I would try checking the box that says to remember your password when linking a table and see if that helps.