# Remove login prompt with SQL linked tables in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have an issue similar to this one: [SQL Server 2008: ODBC connection problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998924/sql-server-2008-odbc-connection-problems)

But mine is unique because I already have the "Save Password" option checked when I link my tables, AND it works fine unless I try to open more than one query at a time.

Steps to recreate:

1) Link a SQL table to an Access 2003 front-end, my DSN looks like this:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server
UID=ACD
WSID=ACD
APP=ACD
SERVER=xx.xx.xxx.xx,1053
Description=ACD Connection to SQL Server
Pwd=XXXXXXXX
```

At first I didn't have the PWD line, it doesn't seem to make a difference with or without that.

2) Open 1 query that uses the linked table, no login prompt

3) Open 2nd query while first one still open, get this error followed by login prompt:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. 
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

I can open as many tables as I want directly and I don't get a password prompt.

If I login once, no more prompts until I restart Access, but this isn't an option for my app.

I'm using SQL server auth only, not setup for Windows auth.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post, I did try using the code block format option for the DSN part, but it was still making everything on a single-line, weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a DSN-Less connection to your SQL server, microsft have a support page for this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892490

This should stop the prompts

Comment: +1 - This looks like a good option if it resovles the problem.  This is for an internal project and my boss just gave me some more "real" work, so might be a bit before I can test and accept this answer.  I will get to it though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the password in you connection (see parameter **dbAttachSavePWD**)

```
Dim MyTable As TableDef
Set MyTable = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(TableName, dbAttachSavePWD, SourceTableName, ConnectionString)
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append MyTabl
```

for example to attach sql table [audit].[Details] as AuditDetails you can use the following code:

```
Dim MyTable As TableDef
Set MyTable = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef
    (
      "AuditDetails",
      dbAttachSavePWD,
      "audit.Details",
      "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};APP=TransFlow®;SERVER=sqlServerName;DATABASE=dbName;UID=userName;PWD=password"
    )
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append MyTabl
```